# C# Create EXACT copy of table from ODBC Datasource into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to figure out what my command would look like to create a complete copy of a table from a database I'm connecting to using ODBC, and place that copy into a SQL Server Database.

I connect to the database I have ODBC Access to using the following:

```
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=OdbcDatabaseName");
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_COUNT FROM TABLE_NAME", conn);
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) {
            label1.Text = "Total Rows: " + reader["TOTAL_COUNT"];
        }
        reader.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
```

Basically, I have access to the first database only via ODBC connection.  I'm able to pull data from it without any problem, but I want to do something similar to

```
SELECT * INTO mySQLDatabase.NEWTABLE FROM odbcDatabase.THETABLE
```

How can I accomplish this?  I'm using C# inside Visual Studio.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate. Please reference this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289832/retrieve-odbc-table-and-insert-into-sql-server-ce-database)

Comment: You can use a dataAdapter to fill a data table on your c# code and then send it as a table valued parameter to an sql stored procedure.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Wont that use a huge amount of memory, depending on the size of the source table? With the risk of crashing due to out of memory if the source table is big enough?

Comment: probably. another option is to try to create a linked server between your sql server and your odbc datasource.